# Calculate the year for ending month/day?

Tags: mysql, date

Given:

- Start Year
- Start Month & Start Day
- End Month & End Day

What SQL statement results in TRUE if a date lands between the Start and End days? The problem is in finding the end year so as to get a `start_date` *and* an `end_date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to calculate the end year (so as to derive the `end_date`):

```
end_year = start_year +
  greatest( -1 *
    sign(
      datediff(
        date(
          concat_ws('-', year, end_month, end_day )
        ),
        date(
          concat_ws('-', year, start_month, start_day )
        )
      )
    ), 0
  )
```

Comment: And the advantage of doing this instead of a simple IF statement is...?

Comment: @jpatokal: This actually calculates the correct year for the `end_date`. Your answer *uses* an `end_date` but doesn't show how to calculate its year.

Comment: Your question -- which you've rewritten five times now -- asks how to determine whether a date falls between start and end, not how to calculate the end year.

Comment: @jpatokal: The question has always been: "Given a start month, start day, end month, end day, and a year: how do you calculate whether a given day falls between the start and end?" The problem is calculating the end year and then convert that to a date. It was a difficult question for me to phrase correctly; apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Your question is still whether (= true or false) the date falls between the start and end.  To answer this, you do _not_ need to determine the end year separately, it's enough to compute the correct end date and use that on the fly to check -- drum roll -- whether the date falls between the start and the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert the dates to UNIX timestamps? Then it would be simple less-than or greater-than integer arithmetic.

Comment: MySQL can compare DATETIME types with all the usual comparison operators quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need true/false values, or can you just SELECT?  Assuming $date contains the date you're looking for in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE $date > start_date AND date < end_date;
```

Having the year in a separate field also works, but looks uglier and probably kills performance:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE $date > CONCAT(year, '-', start_date) AND
  $date < CONCAT(year, '-', end_date);
```

And with handling for the end < start case:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE $date > CONCAT(year, '-', start_date) AND $date <
  IF(start_date < end_date,
     CONCAT(year, '-', end_date),
     DATE_ADD(CONCAT(year, '-', end_date), INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
```

Comment: For the end>start case, DATE_ADD(CONCAT(year, '-', end_date), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) should do the trick.

Comment: If you want to do this in SQL, you'll need to cram a CASE or IF in there.

Comment: I don't think a `CASE` or `IF` is absolutely required.